# How to draw a perfect circular button?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button

I want to draw a perfect circular button. 
I tried using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <stroke 
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#065a32" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
      <solid android:color="#eaebec" />
</shape>
```

But i was only able to draw an oval shape, even if i change the parameter:

```
<stroke 
android:width="3dip"/>
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
```

**My Screenshot:**

[image]

I already tried different links of this site but none of them fulfill my need.

**Edit:**

My code for getView() is:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) { 
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

        }
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cell_clicked);
}
```

Comment: You can draw a circle image in photoshop and set it as background to button.Can vary the resolution of image according to screen size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >

  <solid
      android:color="#eaebec" />
</shape>
```

and in your layout where you are setting background use

```
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
```

or whatever size you need the circle to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried your code but still not getting perfect circle. Also i can't give constant parameter to my view i.e it will be varying according to screen size.

Comment: if its varying according to screen size then define size in dimens.xml according to screen size.

Comment: The solution is too cumbersome i.e to replace  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" with  some dimens value.I don't think this is a perfect solution.You are making it too complex . Consider if i need to do it with different button size.

Comment: maon obviously, if you want it to be circle you will have to provide height and width equal. if you want to define height width in oval xml you can write <size 
          android:width="50dp"
          android:height="50dp"/> in shape.

Comment: my height and width are always equals as iam placing the button inside gridview.

Comment: if its same, then it should be a circle. if you are putting it in getView of any adapter, please post the code, I'll see if I can be of any help.

Comment: @user2749218 Rachit is correct; however, if you claim that your gridview is using an equal width & height, this should work. Which leads me to believe, you are using this shape as a background to the TextView, and not its parent.

Answer (score 0):

use this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#9F2200"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

and in your layout

```
android:background="@drawable/button"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your drawable folder create the following

**circular_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:innerRadius="15dp"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#ce2c2c" />

</shape>
```

add the below attribute to any button to make it circular

```
android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
```

**Output**

[image: Output]